# Drupal 7: fastest way to check if db entry exists

Tags: drupal-7

how i can fastest check, if db entry exists? i use this code:

```
$exists = db_query('SELECT tid FROM {taxonomy_index} WHERE tid = 1 AND nid = 1 LIMIT 1');
        if($exists->rowCount() > 0){
          drupal_set_message("exists");
         }
```

Answer (score 9):

I would do:

```
$result = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'ti')
  ->fields('ti', array('tid'))
  ->condition('tid', 1)
  ->condition('nid', 1)
  ->range(0, 1)
  ->execute()
  ->rowCount();

if ($result) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Exists'));
}
```

Not related to your question, but you should always use placeholders to guard against SQL Injection - though if you use the query builder like above then it takes care of that for you. Also, you should always use the t() function when writing text to screen.

Comment: hmm, nice way, but i can't say, that is the fastest way :) vote up!

Comment: This way is fine, the columns are indexed anyway so I can't see this being slow enough to warrant finding another way. Might be worth timing how long the query takes and posting back, take a look at these functions http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/timer_

Comment: Just doing `db_query('SELECT tid FROM {taxonomy_index} WHERE tid = :tid AND nid = :nid LIMIT 1', [:tid'' => 1, ':nid=> 1])` is safe enough for a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 6):

`db_select()` is way slower than `db_query()`. See [this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1200/given-that-db-select-is-much-slower-than-db-query-why-would-i-want-to-use-it) for scenarios where `db_select()` fits better than `db_query()`.

`db_query()->fetchField()` is the simplest approach. See the following snippet:

```php
// Returns string(5) "admin"
var_dump(db_query('select name from {users} where uid = 1')->fetchField());

// Returns bool(false)
var_dump(db_query('select name from {users} where uid = -1')->fetchField());
```

Comment: This is the best example I've seen yet for how to replace Drupal 6's `db_result()` function (i.e. `if ( db_result($query) ){ // do stuff } else { // no records  }` )